# How can I play a video automatically when i start my pc

Tags: video, task

I want that a video play's when I start my PC.
Does anyone know how I can do that please let me know
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a shortcut to the file in your start up folder.

You can find your start up folder by pressing "Win+r" and then entering `shell:startup`.

Then right click your video file and click "create shortcut" then put that shortcut file in the start up folder.

Comment: It works but there is a delay of a few seconds and it would be nice if it is in fullscreen and also closes on its own.

Comment: If you make VLC your default player then you can configure both of those things.

Comment: Thanks it works.